# Column's MainAxisSize.min and ListView's shrinkWrap: true are not working when inside a container with full height

Tags: flutter, dart

If you create a container that takes the full height of the screen and place either a Column with its mainAxisSize property as MainAxisSize.min or a ListView with its shrinkWrap property as true these values are ignored and the Column/ListView will take up the full height of the container.

Here are code examples to illustrate this:

```
///Column
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [
          Text('1'),
          Text('2'),
          Text('3'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

OR

```
///ListView
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: const [
          Text('1'),
          Text('2'),
          Text('3'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I have a column or ListView only take up the size of its content when it's placed inside a container that has the full height of the window?

Comment: Why there are 2 `Scaffold`s?

Comment: I'm showing an example of each. One for Column and one for ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap it inside a `Column` and include
`Expanded/Flexible` for other widgets like below example:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: Column(children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: const [
              Text('1'),
              Text('2'),
              Text('3'),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```